# @Builder, @NoArgsConstructos and @AllArgsConstructor?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle

What are the meanings of those Spring Annotations and which product is behind them?

@Builder

@NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor

Comment: where is the Gradle bit? :D is there no JavaDoc on them annotations ? or some documentation?

Comment: In IDEA you can holding Ctrl key hover over the annotation and you'll see to package it's coming from.

Answer (score 4):

These annotations are not Spring annotations, it's from [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/all), which can generate getters/setters, constructors, and a lot more things...

Answer (score 0):

These annotations are [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) annotations.
For details, you can visit: https://projectlombok.org/